# How to accurately find quest NPCs?

Tags: fable-3

I'm getting very frustrated with playing Fable 3 as I find the quest tracking system and map to be very unintuitive.

Is there any way to find quest npc's other than marking the quest as active and teleporting near them? Sometimes I find that it teleports me quite a long way away from them and then I struggle to find the right person. Especially in town, such as Brightwall.

I also find that during delivery missions if you open the map to find the npc, then close and re-open it the npc will have moved! Is this a bug or normal?

Are there any tips, mods or suggestions for how to improve the quest tracking and map?